# The semaphore timeout period has expired in Azure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, semaphore

Got this message today on my ASP.NET MVC application running in Azure:

[image]

while the instances were transitioning, swapping the Prod and Staging slots

Answer (score 0):

Error went away once the instances finished transitioning.  If that doesn't solve the problem for you, may be worth deleting what's in the Staging slot (not just Stopping it), redeploying to Staging, and trying the swap again.